# How to delete a file without an extension?

Tags: python

I have made a function for deleting files:

```
def deleteFile(deleteFile):
    if os.path.isfile(deleteFile):
        os.remove(deleteFile)
```

However, when passing a FIFO-filename (without file-extension), this is not accepted by the os-module.
Specifically I have a subprocess create a FIFO-file named 'Testpipe'.
When calling:

```
os.path.isfile('Testpipe')
```

It results to `False`. The file is not in use/open or anything like that. Python runs under Linux.

How can you correctly delete a file like that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`isfile` checks for *regular* file.

You could workaround it like this by checking if it exists but not a directory or a symlink:

```
def deleteFile(filename):
    if os.path.exists(filename) and not os.path.isdir(filename) and not os.path.islink(filename):
        os.remove(filename)
```